# How can I let people change stuff from my database, without giving them the permission to change everything?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

I am kinda a beginner in building working public projects, like projects that can be used by any people, and that are public. And I have a problem with my database. So this project will have a standard & premium subscription, the standard one is the default one, the premium one you need to active it, by entering a license key.

I made a form where people can enter their license, but now I have a problem. So my database rules are set in a way that anyone can read his own details from the database, but can't write/change anything to the database.

But if the license is valid and they want to become premium, I need to make them able to change data in the database, but they can't. So my question is how can make something like: The user send a request, the server checks if the license is valid and then the server changes the information in the database. Without letting the user change information in the database.

Sorry, if I didn't explained it well and sorry if this sounds like a real basic question, but this stuff really confuses me.

I am trying to do this in firebase.

Comment: This is a matter of basic authentication. The number of ways to solve this is pretty much endless.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you structured your licenses and database, but otherwise, it's pretty much as you said:
"The user send a request, the server checks if the license is valid and then the server changes the information in the database. Without letting the user change information in the database."

You can achieve that easily with a Cloud Function. Then the client/user will call it with their license code. The function will check their license against a list of valid codes (probably in your database as well - in a location where the normal users don't have either read or write access), and update the user's status.
Furthermore, it seems like you'll either need to change the permission on your user data, for example, to restrict the user to automatically upgrade themselves. You can for example make a rule that a client can set their plan to free (i.e. while signing up and creating the data or if downgrading), but only an admin can set it to a paid plan.
Otherwise, if you don't want to change the permissions on your user object, then you need to store the information somewhere else, though you'll have to still restrict the write access.